# Should I be concerned about a ceiling light fixture that was installed without the mounting bracket?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, light

The last piece of my move was to install my new light fixtures from my last place and I finally hired a general contractor to do so. After he left, I realized that I had not given him the mounting brackets that I had stored and labelled in separate sandwich bags... which explain why he was having a hard time lining up screws and finding screws the right length... I feel like a dummy.

Everything seems to be tightly and securely installed to the ceiling, just without the original screws and mounting bracket. Should I be concerned that over time the screws will fall and the ceiling light will smash to its death and start a massive fire or am I overthinking it? D'uh.

I'd love to avoid spending more $ for my dumb mistake, but should I have him come back and re-do them with the proper mounting supplies?

Comment: It really depends on the box and fixture, the brackets are for different sized / and shaped boxes, or to rotate the fixture so it’s square with a wall or other fixtures trying to hit a hole that is covered is really tough the brackets make it easier and may not be required at all.

Comment: Yeah, we can't answer this question without knowing exactly what was done.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting brackets for all light fixtures I’ve ever dealt with are fairly simple. There are some variations but they accomplish the same purpose: they are secured to the box and then have either a couple of screws (common for wall-mounted fixtures like sconces) or a lamp nipple (common for ceiling-mounted fixtures) that secure the actual fixture or fixture chain to the box. Some use both screws and a nipple. It’s a fairly standard affair once you have the right screws, even if they’re not the originals. The contractor would have used his own brackets and screws.

In short, I wouldn’t be concerned unless you have reason to believe the contractor is unqualified.